# Xampplite PHPmyAdmin wont prompt to ask for username and password

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a **Xampplite** on my thump drive and when i type localhost:8080/phpmyadmin it goes straight to gui that i can build tables and not prompting me for any username and password.

The question how may i go about solving this?
I tried changing the password to a new one but the same thing happen( it skips the password and username prompt).

2nd if I type a wrong password in the config.inc.php file it prompt me that i have a password and am not using it.
you know that error with Yes e.g 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

remember or note if i type the correct password in the `config.inc.php` file i go to `http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php`

why am i not getting the username and password prompt? please i need some help

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to the phpmyadmin security tab and change all the passwords there.

Comment: as in these two:MYSQL SECTION: "ROOT" PASSWORD annd XAMPP DIRECTORY PROTECTION (.htaccess)?

Comment: Heh whaqt is the default of xamp DIRECTORY PROTECTION (.htaccess) i had never change it is blank

Comment: follow these steps http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Administration/Install-XAMPP-on-Windows/1/

Comment: i did somthing really awful i deleted htaccess file

Comment: i did what u said but all it did was ask me for username and password for the server not phpMyAdmin

Comment: u need to set the password for the phpmyadmin